# Do Delphi Linux apps on Ubuntu servers have a minimum RAM requirement for console-only applications?

Tags: ubuntu, delphi, memory, ram, openvz

I plan to write several programs for my website using Delphi for Linux. Can I get by with 256 MB of memory, or do Delphi Linux apps require more memory to run than what is available on a Ubuntu minimal server over OpenVZ?

Comment: Impossible to say since we have no information of what your applications will be doing at all.

Answer (score 1):

As Windows, Linux has a virtual memory system(Do not confuse with virtual machine). It means that if there is not enough physical memory for the loaded programs, then the kernel will swap memory blocks to the hard disk (Or whatever mass storage) in a dedicated partition or dedicated file called "swap" (https://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/vm-intro.html).

You start getting "out of memory" error when the swap is full.

This swapping takes time and so it slow down the whole system but it still works.

This is for general Linux working. No idea of how behave OpenVZ.